# Laravel auth attempting event is firing in the wrong segment / name

Tags: laravel

Inside `EventServiceProvider` I have this.

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Auth::guard('admin')->attempting(function($user){
        GoogleAuthenticator::onLogin($user);
    });
}
```

When I go `Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(...)` the event is triggered as expected.

But, when I go `Auth::guard('web')->attempt(...)` the event is **also** triggered, this is not expected. why? isn't the name supposed to be the trigger segment?

Thanks